# Each loop to check if image src contains string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a loop that will check the src of all images and if the src contains "null" it will give that image a placeholder/backup image.

So far I have this code which works, however not all images that contain null have that url, so it's not ideal

```
    $("img").each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr("src") == "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185null"){
            $(this).attr("src", "/img/imagenotavailable.png");
        }
    });
```

This is what I've tried using indexOf, however I get "Cannot read property indexOf undefined"

```
   $("img").each(function(){
        if ($(this).src.indexOf("null")){
            $(this).attr("src", "/img/imagenotavailable.png");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use `.attr('src')` to access the attribute, to start with, just like you're doing in the first code block

Comment: `if ($(this).attr('src').indexOf("null")>=0){`

Comment: Thanks both of you it works, I didn't think to add ">=0" to the end of the if statement

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you. try this

```
$('img').each(function(i, elem){

    if(!elem.src || elem.indexOf("null") >= 0) {
         $(element).attr("src", "/img/imagenotavailable.png")
     }
})
```